# Beautifull soup: Get text inside table (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to get the value (1.212,00) from inside a table using Beautifullsoup but the tr doesn't have a defined class this is my attempt:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www-sdc/ResultadoSalCon.asp"
bs = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

trs = (
    bs.find("td", {"b": "SALÁRIO-BASE"})
        .find("table", {"class": "titulo"})
        .findAll("tr")
)

for tr in trs:
    if trs.index(tr) == 2:
        tds = tr.findAll("td")

        for td in tds:
            if tds.index(td) == 3:
                valor = td.get_text()

print(valor)
```

this is input:

```
  bs.find("td", {"b": "SALÁRIO-BASE"})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

this is the html of the site that I am trying to collect the data:

```
<p align="center" class="titulo"><b> COMPETÊNCIA: 01/2022</b></p>
<table border="1" width="80%" height="21" class="titulo"  cellSpacing="0" cellPadding = "2" align="center">
    <tr align="center" height="17">
        <td><b>CLASSE</b></td>
        <td><b>SALÁRIO-BASE </b></td>
        <td><b>ALÍQUOTA-AUTÔNOMO (%)</b></td>
        <td><b>ALÍQUOTA-EMPREGADOR (%)</b></td>
        <td><b>CONTRIBUIÇÃO-AUTÔNOMO </b></td>
        <td><b>CONTRIBUIÇÃO-EMPREGADOR </b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td align="center">              1.212,00</td>
        <td align="center">     20,00</td>
        <td align="center">     20,00</td>
        <td align="center">                242,40</td>
        <td align="center">                242,40</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">10</td>
        <td align="center">              7.087,22</td>
        <td align="center">     20,00</td>
        <td align="center">     20,00</td>
        <td align="center">              1.417,44</td>
        <td align="center">              1.417,44</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Could you add the html as text in the post?

Comment: yes @Mihail-CosminMunteanu

Comment: Is that url you're trying to access correct?

Comment: yes he is but he has private access I will look for a site with the similar code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
html = '''
<p align="center" class="titulo"><b> COMPETÊNCIA: 01/2022</b></p>
<table border="1" width="80%" height="21" class="titulo"  cellSpacing="0" cellPadding = "2" align="center">
    <tr align="center" height="17">
        <td><b>CLASSE</b></td>
        <td><b>SALÁRIO-BASE </b></td>
        <td><b>ALÍQUOTA-AUTÔNOMO (%)</b></td>
        <td><b>ALÍQUOTA-EMPREGADOR (%)</b></td>
        <td><b>CONTRIBUIÇÃO-AUTÔNOMO </b></td>
        <td><b>CONTRIBUIÇÃO-EMPREGADOR </b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td align="center">              1.212,00</td>
        <td align="center">     20,00</td>
        <td align="center">     20,00</td>
        <td align="center">                242,40</td>
        <td align="center">                242,40</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">10</td>
        <td align="center">              7.087,22</td>
        <td align="center">     20,00</td>
        <td align="center">     20,00</td>
        <td align="center">              1.417,44</td>
        <td align="center">              1.417,44</td>
</table>

'''
dfs = pd.read_html(html)
df = dfs[0]
new_header = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.columns = new_header
print(df)
```

This will return:

```
CLASSE  SALÁRIO-BASE    ALÍQUOTA-AUTÔNOMO (%)   ALÍQUOTA-EMPREGADOR (%) CONTRIBUIÇÃO-AUTÔNOMO   CONTRIBUIÇÃO-EMPREGADOR
1   1   1.212,00    2000    2000    24240   24240
2   10  7.087,22    2000    2000    1.417,44    1.417,44
```

You can now access various information from that dataframe, like df['SALÁRIO-BASE'][1] (which would return '1.212,00').

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems with your code:

1. How you were finding the relevant table (you were looking for the table inside a td):

Replace this:

```
trs = (
    bs.find("td", {"b": "SALÁRIO-BASE"})
        .find("table", {"class": "titulo"})
        .findAll("tr")
)
```

With this:

```
trs = (
    bs.find("table", {"class": "titulo"})
        .findAll("tr")
)
```

2. And the way you were navigating the table tree. Keep in mind that the tr and td index starts at zero:

Replace this:

```
if trs.index(tr) == 2:
if tds.index(td) == 3:
```

With this:

```
if trs.index(tr) == 1:
if tds.index(td) == 1:
```

Complete code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www-sdc/ResultadoSalCon.asp"
bs = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

trs = (
    bs.find("table", {"class": "titulo"})
        .findAll("tr")
)

for tr in trs:
    if trs.index(tr) == 1:
        tds = tr.findAll("td")
        for td in tds:
            if tds.index(td) == 1:
                valor = td.get_text()

print(valor)
```